# animating custom shapes in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm new to canvas in html5 and would like to know how to animate a custom shape with lots of coordinates. I searched the web but with n o results. I'm only seeing results for circles or squares.

Here's an example of a random drawing. I would like it to move around the screen without setting coordinates for each point. http://jsfiddle.net/ZJdus/

```
var drawing = function(){
// rand drawing drawing
  context.strokeStyle = "red";
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(318, 200);
    context.lineTo(183, 87);
    context.lineTo(446, 125);
    context.lineTo(446, 202);
    context.lineTo(383, 236);
    context.lineTo(318, 202);
    context.lineTo(318, 125);
    context.lineTo(446, 125);
    context.lineTo(183, 236);
    context.lineTo(318, 125);
    context.lineTo(383, 187);
    context.lineTo(383, 125);
    context.lineTo(613, 180);
    context.lineTo(446,400);
    context.lineTo(413, 180);
    context.lineTo(350, 180);
    context.lineTo(318, 202);
    context.lineTo(350, 180);
    context.lineTo(183, 125);
    context.stroke();
```

};

Is there a way to achieve this?

I'm also fairly new to Javascript so please explain as much as possible if you can.

Thanks

Comment: So you want all points to move the same amount in the same direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `translate()` before you redraw the shape:

```
/// clear canvas before each redraw
context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);

/// translate canvas (move origin)
context.translate(deltaX, deltaY);

... draw points here...

/// reset translate (faster than save()/restore())
context.translate(-deltaX, -deltaY);
```

### [Modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/ZJdus/3/)

Optionally, instead of resetting the translate just use it as delta values directly instead of the absolute delta as now.

You can also add the delta values directly on your coordinates but that is slower than using the translate approach.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to play around with it and let you know how it works out. I did look up translate awhile back, but thought it only moved from pointA to pointB and stopped. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I learned a lot. I will be giving back and answering questions for others :)

Comment: @user2856111 Also see Zach's answer which is a good option in principle and provides better performance if you need to update the same graphics often. I tried to keep it simple/basic in mine as you state you're a beginner, but caching the drawing to an off-screen canvas is often better (performance-wise) but can be a bit more "complex" to maintain. Something to look into later if it doesn't appeal at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

If your shape doesn't change, you should absolutely not redraw it every frame. Instead draw the shape once to a buffer canvas and then use drawImage at the location to animate the shape.

```
var drawing = //same as your code above only context is a buffer canvas...

contextOfDisplayedCanvas.drawImage(canvasWithShape, shape.x, shape.y);
```

Let me know if that doesn't make sense and I can expand.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain more? I started to learn Javascript 2 two weeks ago and decided to jump into Canvas.

Comment: Here's a link with some info: http://kaioa.com/node/103. I'm at work now, but I'll edit my post with a more specific example for you when I get done.

Comment: Thanks. After playing around, this is what I came up with http://jsfiddle.net/claireC/Y7MFq/. I don't understand how to get the triangle to move on its own and not the whole canvas. Obviously, I'm missing something, but I can't quite nail it on the head at the moment.

Comment: So I found the problem :) It was this line of code context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); After removing it from the animation frame everything went smooth.  Thanks to both you guys for your help!!! Now time to figure out how to use multiple objects.